# Better way for inter-project development (with Gradle or IntelliJ)

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, gradle

I have two projects (not modules), `A` and `B`. Project `B` depends on `A`. I can run only `B`. Dependency is set through maven repo, where local repo is the first to look into.

When I need to change something in dependency `A`, there is a flow I repeat all the time:

- go to `A` in IDE
- build `A`
- install to local maven repo: `gradlew install`
- go to `B` in IDE
- refresh gradle project
- run `B`

Is there any better way how to skip all these steps? I was thinking into having a 'master' dummy project in my IDE (intelliJ) that will contain these two, so I can run and change everything at once.

Comment: In eclispe you can have multiple project in the same workspace, I think it is the same in intelliJ. When this is the case (maven / gradle ) plugin can use the current build (in EDI) to do the dependency. No need of 'master' dummy project.

Comment: There is no workspace concept in IntelliJ. You can have a project and one or more modules. But not multiple project (afaik). But I will check.

Comment: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Project+Organization?pageVersion=13

Comment: @Mr_Thorynque but I can't run one project with classpath of the another. Hence, I can only make projects as module, which brings me to the "Master" project idea

Comment: if you use gradle or maven you have not to manipulate projets classpath. Let the IDE plugin deals with dependencies and it'll works.

Comment: @Mr_Thorynque sorry not the classpath but source change. With 2 open IDEAs i must follow above steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gradle 3.1 introduces [composite builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html). With it you can, e.g., create new project, that is a composite of other projects. This new project contains only two files:

### settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name='we'    
includeBuild '../api.java'
includeBuild '../common'
includeBuild '../engine'
includeBuild '../io'
includeBuild '../io-redis'
```

### build.gradle

```
task buildServer {
    dependsOn gradle.includedBuild('engine').task(':server:build')
}
```

Released soon, IDEA 2016.3 will support this.

Answer (score 2):

One way to solve this is to create a master project, include both of your project in this project's `settings.gradle`:

```
include "A", "B"
```

And change project B's `build.gradle` to use [Conditional substitution](https://docs.gradle.org/3.0/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:conditional_dependency_substitution):

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.dependencySubstitution.all { DependencySubstitution dependency ->
        if (dependency.requested instanceof ModuleComponentSelector && dependency.requested.group == "org.example") {
            def targetProject = findProject(":${dependency.requested.module}")
            if (targetProject != null) {
                dependency.useTarget targetProject
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This way if you execute `./gradlew B:build` in the root project, gradle will build project A too.

Importing this root project in IDEA will work too.

Comment: What if `A` is multi-modular project? I am not able to build it using `./gradlew A:build`, executed in the root. But I build `B` (B depends on A) - but not `A`.